# All 8 cores at 100% usage but frequency isn't max?

Tags: linux, cpu

I'm compiling something with -j64 to allow multiprocessing (88 was recommended, but I felt that was too high).

All of my cores are consistently 100% usage, however the frequency of the processor isn't hitting it's max when I look in lscpu:

```
CPU MHz:               3123.046
CPU max MHz:           3900.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
```

This is on a dell laptop - is there a power management system (I haven't done powertop or anything) that would be limiting the cores, or is this just I/O overhead that's keeping the cpu from having data?

Edit : this is a `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ` (lscpu says `@ 2.90GHz`)

Comment: The usual advice is `NUM_CPUS * 2`, not `NUM_CPUS ^ 2`. ;) // You didn’t specify what CPU we’re talking about.

Comment: I agree that it seems high - shouldn't it be `(CPUS * 2) + 1 or 2` so that you have all the hyperthreads plus a few when one goes io-bound? I added cpu to the queston

Comment: As per the answer below and https://ark.intel.com/products/97496/Intel-Core-i7-7820HQ-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz your processor normal clock speed is 2.9GHz with the option of boosting up to 3.9GHz if allowed by thermal and power limits. If all the cores are fully active then you ***will*** be hitting one of those limits which will prevent you from permanently being at 3.9GHz. That you are still above your nominal 2.9GHz means your system is functioning well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3900MHz speed you quoted is the maximum "turbo" frequency and not something that can be sustained in every use case.

From [Intel's website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html):

> Max Turbo Frequency refers to the maximum single-core processor
>   frequency that can be achieved with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology.

And:

> Availability and frequency upside of Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.0
>   state depends upon a number of factors including, but not limited to,
>   the following:
>
> - Type of workload
> - Number of active cores
> - Estimated current consumption
> - Estimated power consumption
> - Processor temperature

Since you are utilising all cores the CPU is keeping them all active which generates a lot of heat and uses a lot of power so it can't run at the full 3900MHz frequency. If you ran the compilation as a single-threaded process you could expect to see higher frequencies as it ramps up a single core (unless the cooling on your laptop cannot cope).

Comment: I had forgotten about turboboost - Thank you for the clarification!